# Keras: LSTM with class weights

Tags: keras, lstm

my question is quite closely related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms) but also goes beyond it.

I am trying to implement the following [LSTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM4ju.png) in Keras where

- the number of timesteps be `nb_tsteps=10`
- the number of input features is `nb_feat=40`
- the number of LSTM cells at each time step is `120`
- the LSTM layer is followed by TimeDistributedDense layers

From the question referenced above I understand that I have to present the input data as

`nb_samples, 10, 40`

where I get `nb_samples` by rolling a window of length `nb_tsteps=10` across the original timeseries of shape `(5932720, 40)`. The code is hence

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(120, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), 
  return_sequences=True, consume_less='gpu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(50, activation='relu')))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(20, activation='relu')))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(10, activation='relu')))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')))
```

Now to my question (assuming the above is correct so far):
The binary responses (0/1) are heavily imbalanced and I need to pass a `class_weight` dictionary like `cw = {0: 1, 1: 25}` to `model.fit()`. However I get an exception `class_weight not supported for 3+ dimensional targets`. This is because I present the response data as `(nb_samples, 1, 1)`. If I reshape it into a 2D array `(nb_samples, 1)` I get the exception `Error when checking model target: expected timedistributed_5 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (5932720, 1)`.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you should use `sample_weight` with `sample_weight_mode='temporal'`.

From the Keras docs:

> sample_weight: Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used
>   for scaling the loss function (during training only). You can either
>   pass a flat (1D) Numpy array with the same length as the input samples
>   (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the case of temporal
>   data, you can pass a 2D array with shape (samples, sequence_length),
>   to apply a different weight to every timestep of every sample. In this
>   case you should make sure to specify sample_weight_mode="temporal" in
>   compile().

In your case you would need to supply a 2D array with the same shape as your labels.

Comment: I do not understand why sample_weight (with sample_weight_mode="temporal") is relevant. We are talking about class weights here, not sample weights, right? sample_weight_mode="temporal" just assigns a weight to every sample in every time step, but it has nothing to do with class labels at all?

Answer (score 1):

If this is still an issue.. I think the TimeDistributed Layer expects and returns a 3D array (kind of similar to if you have return_sequences=True in the regular LSTM layer). Try adding a Flatten() layer or another LSTM layer at the end before the prediction layer.

```
d = TimeDistributed(Dense(10))(input_from_previous_layer)
lstm_out = Bidirectional(LSTM(10))(d)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(lstm_out)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `temporal` is a workaround. Check out this [stack](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/31542). The issue is also documented on [github](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3653).