# In Keras, what exactly am I configuring when I create a stateful `LSTM` layer with N `units`?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

The first arguments in a normal `Dense` layer is also `units`, and is the number of neurons/nodes in that layer. A standard LSTM unit however looks like the following:

[image]

(This is a reworked version of "[Understanding LSTM Networks](http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)")

In Keras, when I create an LSTM object like this `LSTM(units=N, ...)`, am I actually creating `N` of these LSTM units? Or is it the size of the "Neural Network" layers inside the LSTM unit, i.e., the `W`'s in the formulas? Or is it something else?

For context, I'm working based on [this example code](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/stateful_lstm.py).

The following is the documentation: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/

It says:

> units: Positive integer, dimensionality of the output space.

It makes me think it is the number of outputs from the Keras LSTM "layer" object. Meaning the next layer will have `N` inputs. Does that mean there actually exists `N` of these LSTM units in the LSTM layer, or maybe that that exactly *one* LSTM unit is run for `N` iterations outputting `N` of these `h[t]` values, from, say, `h[t-N]` up to `h[t]`?

If it only defines the number of outputs, does that mean the input still can be, say, just *one*, or do we have to manually create lagging input variables `x[t-N]` to `x[t]`, one for each LSTM unit defined by the `units=N` argument?

As I'm writing this it occurs to me what the argument `return_sequences` does. If set to `True` all the `N` outputs are passed forward to the next layer, while if it is set to `False` it only passes the last `h[t]` output to the next layer. Am I right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241985/understanding-lstm-units-vs-cells

Comment: @Peteris I don't think tagging a questions as "duplicate" across stack exchange sites is a thing. This question also pertains to Keras, an abstraction layer on top of Tensorflow. Anyway, the link is helpful and a good reference so thanks.

Comment: Check this - https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/58854907.  A pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms/38737941#38737941) for further information, although it is based on Keras-1.x API.

Basically, the `unit` means the dimension of the inner cells in LSTM. Because in LSTM, the dimension of inner cell (C_t and C_{t-1} in the graph), output mask (o_t in the graph) and hidden/output state (h_t in the graph) should have the **SAME** dimension, therefore you output's dimension should be  `unit`-length as well.

And `LSTM` in Keras only define exactly one LSTM block, whose cells is of `unit`-length. If you set `return_sequence=True`, it will return something with shape: `(batch_size, timespan, unit)`. If `false`, then it just return the last output in shape `(batch_size, unit)`.

As for the input, you should provide input for every timestamp. Basically, the shape is like `(batch_size, timespan, input_dim)`, where `input_dim` can be different from the `unit`. If you just want to provide input at the first step, you can simply pad your data with zeros at other time steps.

Comment: So, that means the `unit` means the size of the vector that is being outputted by every time-step LSTM cell. But, how does Keras know how many of these LSTM cells to use OR will be required to train on the data? I mean, it's easy to figure out the no. of LSTM cells required for the input(specified in `timespan`), but, how to figure out the no. of LSTM units required in the output?

Answer (score 26):

> Does that mean there actually exists N of these LSTM units in the LSTM layer, or maybe that that exactly one LSTM unit is run for N iterations outputting N of these h[t] values, from, say, h[t-N] up to h[t]?

First is true. In that Keras LSTM layer there are N LSTM units or cells.

```
keras.layers.LSTM(units, activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid', use_bias=True, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', recurrent_initializer='orthogonal', bias_initializer='zeros', unit_forget_bias=True, kernel_regularizer=None, recurrent_regularizer=None, bias_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None, kernel_constraint=None, recurrent_constraint=None, bias_constraint=None, dropout=0.0, recurrent_dropout=0.0, implementation=1, return_sequences=False, return_state=False, go_backwards=False, stateful=False, unroll=False)
```

If you plan to create simple LSTM layer with 1 cell you will end with this:
[image]
And this would be your model.

```
N=1
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(N))
```

For the other models you would need N>1
[image]

Comment: why would we use lstm in `one-to-one` model?

Comment: If neural network is matrix transform followed by non-linearity, there are several neural networks in LSMT. I have no clear idea why would I use just the single LSMT cell in practice.

Comment: So `N` is the number of blue cells?

Comment: @dvdblk, Yes, N should be the blue cells, or [LSTM out space](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/)

Comment: isn't the blue cells computed from the input time step. for eg we have an LSTM(32) layer and if we input `(2,1,24)` which corresponds to `(batch size, time step, features)` then this will have only 1 blue cell.

Answer (score 14):

### How many instances of "LSTM chains"

The proper intuitive explanation of the 'units' parameter for Keras recurrent neural networks is that with `units=1` you get a RNN as described in textbooks, and with `units=n` you get a layer which consists of `n` independent copies of such RNN - they'll have identical structure, but as they'll be initialized with different weights, they'll compute something different.

Alternatively, you can consider that in an LSTM with `units=1` the key values (f, i, C, h) are scalar; and with `units=n` they'll be vectors of length `n`.

Comment: So if I have an input sequence with N timepoints, the number of cells is N (when unrolling the LSTM) and if I set `units=1` then this is it. If I set it to `10` it will produce 10 independent copies of my LSTM chains that are N (N cells). Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

"Intuitively" just like a dense layer with 100 dim (Dense(100)) will have 100 neurons. Same way LSTM(100) will be a layer of 100 'smart neurons' where each neuron is the figure you mentioned and the output will be a vector of 100 dimensions