# How to deciding number of units in the Embedding, LSTM, layers in the deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, word-embedding

So this is the part of the code of a deep learning model which I am building using keras function API.
Can You Please tell me how to decide Number of Units in each layer.

```
input_text_layer = Input(shape=(34,),name="Input_sequence)

e1 = Embedding(input_dim=40000, output_dim=no_of_output_dim, input_length=34)(input_text_layer)

lstm_layer = LSTM(no_of_lstm_units, dropout=0.2, return_sequences=True)(e1)

flatten_layer = Flatten()(lstm_layer)
...some dense layers...
```

How to decide the values of `no_of_output_dim` in the Embedding layer and `no_of_lstm_units` given that all other values which are hard coded are constant.

Comment: I think this has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44273249/in-keras-what-exactly-am-i-configuring-when-i-create-a-stateful-lstm-layer-wi

Comment: I still don't understand that is ```no_of_lstm_units``` depends upon ```no_of_output_dim``` and ```input_length``` both?

Comment: These are hyperparameters that are tuned using something like Grid Search, basically you try a bunch of parameters and keep the best performing ones.