# How to generate more than 1 output per input in LSTM?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, nlp, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Assume this is my model:

```
_________________________________________________________________ 
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #    ================================================================= 
embedding_16 (Embedding)     (None, 10, 500)          71500      _________________________________________________________________ 
lstm_31 (LSTM)               (None, 10, 500)          2002000    _________________________________________________________________ 
dropout_15 (Dropout)         (None, 10, 500)          0          _________________________________________________________________ 
time_distributed_16          (None, 10, 500)          250500    _________________________________________________________________ 
softmax (Activation)         (None, 10, 500)           0     =================================================================
```

But I want to have in my last layer:

```
softmax (Activation)         (None, 100, 1000)           0
```

I have been trying to do this for hours. I don't know if this is possible or not. I don't think you can change output size of LSTM (looking at its model) but is there a layer that i can add so that it generates , say, 10 ouputs per input?

In simple words, assume I want to my model to generate 10 words for each word i put in. I hope I am able to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of looking at the "multiple output" here (and by "here" I take a guess that you are using `keras` library - it seems so from the printout).

In a simple case, having e.g. `Dense(10)` layer would solve it. The "secret sauce" in using `TimeDistributed` layer wrapper as explained in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102332/lstm-keras-api-predicting-multiple-outputs).

The other approach requires using functional API of keras. How to get multiple out is explained in the [docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#multi-input-and-multi-output-models).