# Keras: Dense layer expects 2d matrix after LSTM

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, lstm

My Y_train is a one-hot encoded label matrix.

The shape of my Y_train is `(10, 1000, 3)` because I have three different categories.

My model is defined as:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(1000, 38), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])
```

When I train my model, I get the following error:

> Error when checking target: expected dense_83 to have 2 dimensions,
>   but got array with shape (8, 1000, 3)

This occurs because my Y_train is a 3d matrix, instead of a 2d matrix. The only way I've been able to solve this is by setting `return_sequences=True` but not sure if that will affect my LSTM's output.

Is this the correct way to deal with categorical labels? By setting `return_sequences=True` as a parameter of LSTM?

In other words, is it okay to return_sequences before a Softmax layer?

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I added an edit to emphasize my question at the end, sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Can you elaborate the meaning of second dimension(1000) of `Y_train`?

Comment: @keineahnung2345 i have 10 sequences with 1000 timesteps and 38 features in each timestep! Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102332/lstm-keras-api-predicting-multiple-outputs This should be helpful.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 thanks for sharing that. I'm only able to train with one hot encoded labels when return_sequences is set to True. Any idea why? Otherwise it says it expects the output to have 2 dimensions. One-hot encoded make it 3 dimensions per timestep. (seq_n, timestep, onehot_label)

Comment: One-hot encoding should be ok. It seems you have a label for every timestamp in every sequence, in this case, you should use `return_sequences=True` because otherwise your model output and your label don't match.