# Difference between two Sequence to Sequence Models keras (with and without RepeatVector)

Tags: python, keras, sequence-to-sequence

I try to understand what the difference between this model describde [here](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html), the following one:

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
```

and the sequence to sequence model described here is
[second describion](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html)

What is the difference ? The first one has the RepeatVector while the second does not have that? Is the first model not taking the decoders hidden state as inital state for the prediction ?

Are there a paper describing the first and second one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the model using `RepeatVector`, they're not using any kind of fancy prediction, nor dealing with states. They're letting the model do everything internally and the `RepeatVector` is used to transform a `(batch, latent_dim)` vector (which is not a sequence) into a `(batch, timesteps, latent_dim)` (which is now a proper sequence).

Now, in the other model, without `RepeatVector`, the secret lies in this additional function:

```
def decode_sequence(input_seq):
    # Encode the input as state vectors.
    states_value = encoder_model.predict(input_seq)

    # Generate empty target sequence of length 1.
    target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
    # Populate the first character of target sequence with the start character.
    target_seq[0, 0, target_token_index['\t']] = 1.

    # Sampling loop for a batch of sequences
    # (to simplify, here we assume a batch of size 1).
    stop_condition = False
    decoded_sentence = ''
    while not stop_condition:
        output_tokens, h, c = decoder_model.predict([target_seq] + states_value)

        # Sample a token
        sampled_token_index = np.argmax(output_tokens[0, -1, :])
        sampled_char = reverse_target_char_index[sampled_token_index]
        decoded_sentence += sampled_char

        # Exit condition: either hit max length
        # or find stop character.
        if (sampled_char == '\n' or len(decoded_sentence) > max_decoder_seq_length):
            stop_condition = True

        # Update the target sequence (of length 1).
        target_seq = np.zeros((1, 1, num_decoder_tokens))
        target_seq[0, 0, sampled_token_index] = 1.

        # Update states
        states_value = [h, c]

    return decoded_sentence
```

This runs a "loop" based on a `stop_condition` for creating the time steps one by one. (The advantage of this is making sentences without a fixed length).

It also explicitly takes the states generated in each step (in order to keep the proper connection between each individual step).

---

### In short:

- Model 1: creates the length by repeating the latent vector
- Model 2: creates the length by looping new steps until a stop condition is reached

Comment: you said you can make sentences without a fixed length, would this also possible with timeseries data ? If yes would you be able to provide an example based on a shape of (None, timesteps, number of features) ?

Comment: There is no difference between sentences and timeseries, both are data shaped like `(batch, steps, features)` that are blindly interpreted by the model. --- You can follow exactly the same procedure they used in this model, or you can maybe follow the stateful approach I created in these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47594861/predicting-a-multiple-time-step-forward-of-a-time-series-using-lstm/47719094#47719094 --- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760472/how-to-use-the-keras-model-to-forecast-for-future-dates-or-events/48807811#48807811

Comment: I tried something out but my prediction wants the same batch size as in the training and is not variable. I will make another post with my code for that.

Comment: have look here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51501726/variable-input-for-sequence-to-sequence-autoencoder

Comment: another question is if the model with the RepeatVector is also using the encoders initial state as decoders inital state in the prediction ?

Comment: No, that model uses only the "latend data", nothing else. (It creates its own states as it progresses through the steps, but internally and not seen by the user).