# How to use a Keras RNN model to forecast for future dates or events?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Here is my code fore training the complete model and saving it:

```
num_units = 2
activation_function = 'sigmoid'
optimizer = 'adam'
loss_function = 'mean_squared_error'
batch_size = 10
num_epochs = 100

# Initialize the RNN
regressor = Sequential()

# Adding the input layer and the LSTM layer
regressor.add(LSTM(units = num_units, activation = activation_function, input_shape=(None, 1)))

# Adding the output layer
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))

# Compiling the RNN
regressor.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = loss_function)

# Using the training set to train the model
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = num_epochs)
regressor.save('model.h5')
```

After that I have seen that most of the time people our suggesting the test dataset for checking the prediction which I have attempted as well and got good result.

But the problem is in the usage of the model that I have created. I want to have a forecast for next 30 days or every minute whatsoever. Now I have the trained model but I am not getting what I can do or what code do I use to use the model and forecast the prices for next 30 days or one minute.

Please suggest me the way out. I am stuck at this problem since a week and not able to make any successful attempts.

Here is the link of the repository where one can find the complete runnable code, the model, and the dataset:  [My repository link](https://github.com/JafferWilson/forecastbtc/)

Comment: Is there someone who can help me with the issue? Please let me know.

Comment: I have doubt  regarding the dataset. You provides prices as input which explain how accurate you model is. There is more complexe models not able to predict evolution with such a good accuracy. I guess the second input is the date (not visible in the head (block 3) ?. I'll take a look when I have time but you can take a look at this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqWm8A-dRYg). He is predicting BTC price with bidirectionnal LSTM and social networks sentiments. To finish, you can predict the days after (as you have a daily timestep). If you need mode days, you can create a loop.

Comment: @NicolasM.Sure.. thank you for your time and consideration. But have a look at the code so I can improve. Thanks.

Comment: Why downvote? I do not understand, why people not having any answer start downvoting the question or sometimes try to close it.

Comment: I've slightly modified the dataframe compare to what you've done. Nevertheless, I've added a shifted column to predict the next price but the prediction is still to accurate. I don't know exactly what is wrong but I guess this is due to the fact that we have 1 batch of around 700 timesteps of 1 input and the model is able to understand that there is only a shift. Everytime I tried RNN, I used multiple batches compare to this exercice so I'm also stuck :s. I'll continue to take a look

Comment: @NicolasM. Thank you for your time.. atleast you are helping.. others are only downvoting and disrespecting me for asking question where I am stuck up.

Comment: They are maybe considering this question as "too classic" with maybe similar answers on SO.. but yeah, it's a bit boring. I also forgot to provide you the link to the github where you can find my try (https://github.com/Coni63/SO/tree/master/forecastbtc-master)

Comment: Dear downvoters, do you have any answer for what I have asked?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Well, you need a `stateful=True` model, so you can feed it one prediction after another to get the next and keep the model thinking that each input is not a new sequence, but a sequel to the previous.

**Fixing the code and training**

I see in the code that there is an attempt to make your `y` be a shifte `x` (a good option for predicting the next steps). But there is also a big problem in the preprocessing here:

```
training_set = df_train.values
training_set = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(training_set)

x_train = training_set[0:len(training_set)-1]
y_train = training_set[1:len(training_set)]
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 1, 1))
```

Data for `LSTM` layers must be shaped as `(number_of_sequences, number_of_steps,features)`.

So, you're clearly creating sequences of 1 step only, meaning that your LSTM is not learning sequences at all.  (There is no sequence with only one step).

Assuming that your data is a single unique sequence with 1 feature, it should definitely be shaped as `(1, len(x_train), 1)`.

Naturally, `y_train` should also have the same shape.

This, in its turn, will require that your LSTM layers be `return_sequences=True` - The only way to make `y` have a length in steps. Also, for having a good prediction, you may need a more complex model (because now it will be trully learning).

This done, you train your model until you get a satisfactory result.

---

**Predicting the future**

For predicting the future, you will need `stateful=True` LSTM layers.

Before anything, you reset the model's states: `model.reset_states()` - Necessary every time you're inputting a new sequence into a stateful model.

Then, first you predict the entire `X_train` (this is needed for the model to understand at which point of the sequence it is, in technical words: to create a state).

```
predictions = model.predict(`X_train`) #this creates states
```

And finally you create a loop where you start with the last step of the previous prediction:

```
future = []
currentStep = predictions[:,-1:,:] #last step from the previous prediction

for i in range(future_pred_count):
    currentStep = model.predict(currentStep) #get the next step
    future.append(currentStep) #store the future steps    

#after processing a sequence, reset the states for safety
model.reset_states()
```

---

**Example**

This code does this with a 2-feature sequence, a shifted future step prediction, and a method that is a little different from this answer, but based on the same principle.

I created two models (one `stateful=False`, for training without needing to reset states every time - never forget to reset states when you're starting a new sequence - and the other `stateful=True`, copying the weights from the trained model, for predicting the future)

https://github.com/danmoller/TestRepo/blob/master/TestBookLSTM.ipynb

Comment: This is awesome.... Daniel. This is great atleast you have try to help me,..... I will try your suggestion and if it works, I will accept your answer too.

Comment: Dear Daniel, is it possible for your make changes in my repository code here: https://github.com/JafferWilson/forecastbtc/ I guess that will help me a lot and make understanding.. I am trying to implement the way you have. But can try it out please.

Comment: daniel had you checked my code... because afyer adding your suggestions I am getting lots of error...

Comment: `regressor.add(LSTM(units = num_units, activation = activation_function, input_shape=(None, 1), 
                   stateful=True,return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(1, len(x_train), 1)))` I have made the code something like this with staeful=true

Comment: Here is the gist of error: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/46a469bde3b31cdaa2523874894a167f  Please have a look.... if possible please check the repository link that I have share in the question, so that you can even let me know the necessary changes done for prediction.....

Comment: Do you have an updated version of the code? -- This line will have the error of having both `batch_input_shape` and `input_shape`. In this case, you should use only `batch_input_shape=(1,None,1)` -- considering you have only a single sequence.

Comment: The `None` length is important, since you're going to input a long length for training and short length for predicting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165284/discussion-between-jaffer-wilson-and-daniel-moller).

Comment: HEY @JafferWilson , I would like to ask one thing, did the above answer solves the problem of future value prediction.

Comment: Yes it does. We have to decide what the future value will be. The model does its work well.

Comment: @Jaffer Wilson  Is this code work for you properly? is this predict future value? I tried this code for my code it gave me error , here I have 6 inputs , and I want to get one output value, here is my error "Error when checking input: expected lstm_147_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (2109, 1)"  Can give you any suggestion to me to solve this error ?

Comment: Basic shape mismatch error. LSTM layers expect 3D data, you're giving it a 2D data.

Comment: @ Daniel Möller Thank you for the response, But I tried I didn't get good prediction value. Please can you look at my question , here is te link of my question "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367712/how-to-feed-my-output-prediction-value-as-next-input-value-of-rnn-model-to-for-f"   I am requesting you to please look at my question, I am stuck of this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do in order to predict future values with RNNs is to provide data as *sequences*. Something like this:

```
[0 1 2] --> [3]
[1 2 3] --> [4]
[2 3 4] --> [5]
[3 4 5] --> [6]
[4 5 6] --> [7]
```

RNNs learn the structure of sequences, and therefore need a unique input shape:

```
(n_samples, time_steps, n_features)
```

For instance, the time steps could be 7 if you use every day of the last week.

#### How can I create a dataset for RNNs?

1. [`tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array)

What you'll need to do is provide this function with a) present values, and b) future values. Here, `seq_length` is the number of time steps to use.

```
import tensorflow as tf

seq_length = 3

x = tf.range(25)[:-seq_length]

y = tf.range(25)[seq_length:]

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, y,
                                                          sequence_length=seq_length,
                                                          batch_size=1)

for present_values, next_value in ds.take(5):
    print(tf.squeeze(present_values).numpy(), '-->', next_value.numpy())
```

```
[0 1 2] --> [3]
[1 2 3] --> [4]
[2 3 4] --> [5]
[3 4 5] --> [6]
[4 5 6] --> [7]
```

You can also do the same for multiple variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf

seq_length = 3

x = tf.concat([
    tf.reshape(tf.range(25, dtype=tf.float32)[:-seq_length], (-1, 1)),
    tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0., .24, 25)      [:-seq_length], (-1, 1))], axis=-1)

y = tf.concat([
    tf.reshape(tf.range(25, dtype=tf.float32)[seq_length:], (-1, 1)),
    tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0., .24, 25)      [seq_length:], (-1, 1))], axis=-1)

ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(x, y,
                                                          sequence_length=seq_length,
                                                          batch_size=1)

for present_values, next_value in ds.take(5):
    print(tf.squeeze(present_values).numpy(), '-->', tf.squeeze(next_value).numpy())
    
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])

model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')

history = model.fit(ds)
```

```
[[0.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]] --> [3.   0.03]
[[1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]] --> [4.   0.04]
[[2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]] --> [5.   0.05]
[[3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]] --> [6.   0.06]
[[4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]
 [6.   0.06]] --> [7.   0.07]
```

2. This function

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(25)

def univariate_data(dataset, start_index, end_index, history_size, target_size):
    data, labels = [], []

    start_index = start_index + history_size
    if end_index is None:
        end_index = len(dataset) - target_size

    for i in range(start_index, end_index):
        indices = np.arange(i-history_size, i)
        data.append(np.reshape(dataset[indices], (history_size, 1)))
        labels.append(dataset[i:i+target_size])
    return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

present_values, future_values = univariate_data(x, 0, 9, 3, 3)

for present, next_val in zip(present_values, future_values):
    print(tf.squeeze(present).numpy(), '-->', tf.squeeze(next_val).numpy())
```

```
[0 1 2] --> [3 4]
[1 2 3] --> [4 5]
[2 3 4] --> [5 6]
[3 4 5] --> [6 7]
[4 5 6] --> [7 8]
[5 6 7] --> [8 9]
```

And now for multiple variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

history_size = 3

x = np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(np.arange(25), 1)[:-history_size],
                    np.expand_dims(np.linspace(0., .24, 25), 1)[:-history_size]], axis=1)

y = np.concatenate([np.expand_dims(np.arange(25), 1)[history_size:],
                    np.expand_dims(np.linspace(0., .24, 25), 1)[history_size:]], axis=1)


def multivariate_data(dataset, target, start_index, end_index, history_size,
                      target_size, step, single_step=False):
  data = []
  labels = []
  start_index = start_index + history_size
  if end_index is None:
    end_index = len(dataset) - target_size
  for i in range(start_index, end_index):
    indices = range(i-history_size, i, step)
    data.append(dataset[indices])
    if single_step:
      labels.append(target[i+target_size])
    else:
      labels.append(target[i:i+target_size])

  return np.array(data), np.array(labels)

present_values, future_values = multivariate_data(x, y, 0, 8, history_size, 1, 1)

for present, next_val in zip(present_values, future_values):
    print(tf.squeeze(present).numpy(), '-->', tf.squeeze(next_val).numpy())
```

```
[[0.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]] --> [6.   0.06]
[[1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]] --> [7.   0.07]
[[2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]] --> [8.   0.08]
[[3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]] --> [9.   0.09]
[[4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]
 [6.   0.06]] --> [10.   0.1]
```

3. [`tf.data.Dataset.window`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#window)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

history_size = 3
lookahead = 2

x = tf.range(8)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
ds = ds.window(history_size + lookahead, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(history_size + lookahead))
ds = ds.map(lambda window: (window[:-lookahead], window[-lookahead:]))

for present_values, next_value in ds:
    print(present_values.numpy(), '-->', next_value.numpy())
```

```
[0 1 2] --> [3 4]
[1 2 3] --> [4 5]
[2 3 4] --> [5 6]
[3 4 5] --> [6 7]
```

With multiple variables:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

history_size = 3
lookahead = 2

x = tf.concat([
    tf.reshape(tf.range(20, dtype=tf.float32), (-1, 1)),
    tf.reshape(tf.linspace(0., .19, 20), (-1, 1))], axis=-1)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x)
ds = ds.window(history_size + lookahead, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
ds = ds.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(history_size + lookahead))
ds = ds.map(lambda window: (window[:-lookahead], window[-lookahead:]))

for present_values, next_value in ds.take(8):
    print(tf.squeeze(np.round(present_values, 2)).numpy(), '-->',
          tf.squeeze(np.round(next_value, 2)).numpy())
    print()
```

```
[[0.   0.  ]
 [1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]] --> [[3.   0.03]
                   [4.   0.04]]
[[1.   0.01]
 [2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]] --> [[4.   0.04]
                   [5.   0.05]]
[[2.   0.02]
 [3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]] --> [[5.   0.05]
                   [6.   0.06]]
[[3.   0.03]
 [4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]] --> [[6.   0.06]
                   [7.   0.07]]
[[4.   0.04]
 [5.   0.05]
 [6.   0.06]] --> [[7.   0.07]
                   [8.   0.08]]
[[5.   0.05]
 [6.   0.06]
 [7.   0.07]] --> [[8.   0.08]
                   [9.   0.09]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this code with little modification below in my case. It works fine. Thanks

```
future_pred_count=10
future = []
currentStep = np.array([187, 196, 210])

for i in range(future_pred_count):
    prediction = model.predict(currentStep[np.newaxis, :, np.newaxis]) # set dimentions
    future.append(prediction[0][0]) 
    currentStep = np.append(currentStep[1:], prediction[0][0], axis=None ) #store the future steps
    
print(future)
```