# is it impossible or possible forecast time series for next value using LSTM in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have `x_train` 62796 and `x_test` 15684 and I want to predict the values after that. I seek your advice to forecast the values after that using LSTM in Keras. Here is my code :

```
...
look_back = 20
train_size = int(len(data) * 0.80)
test_size = len(data) - train_size

train = data[0:train_size]
test = data[train_size:len(data)]
x_train, y_train = create_dataset(train, look_back)
x_test, y_test = create_dataset(test, look_back)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
y_train=np.repeat(y_train.reshape(-1,1), 20, axis=1).reshape(-1,20,1)
y_test=np.repeat(y_test.reshape(-1,1), 20, axis=1).reshape(-1,20,1)
...
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(512,  return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(LSTM(1, return_sequences=True))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=64)
p = model.predict(x_test)
```

So, `predictions = model.predict(x_train)` and shape is `(62796, 20, 1)`

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760472/how-to-use-the-keras-model-to-forecast-for-future-dates-or-events) code

```
future = []
currentStep = predictions[-20:, :, :] # -20 is last look_back number

for i in range(10):
    currentStep = model.predict(currentStep)
    future.append(currentStep)
```

In this code future result is :

[image: 1]

but `p = model.predict(x_test)`'s [:4000] result is :

[image: 2]

I want to know how to predict the exact next value. But, The difference between the two results is very large. I don't know where it went wrong or the code went wrong. Here is [full](https://gist.github.com/Lay4U/654f70bd1fb9c4f7d5bdb21ddcb588ab) source.

Comment: [`model.fit`](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit) can accept or create a validation split for you, giving you a loss corresponding to how off your predictions are on the validation-set. Using this, you can try training longer, adjusting learning-rate, architecture and so on, until you reach an acceptable error.

Comment: can you give me some example?