# Tensorflow continous training from input data

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, training-data

I‘m new to tensorflow have a general question:
I have a certain amount of training data and want to do a time series prediction.
The intervals on my training data is one minute and I want to do a prediction for the following minutes based on the new input data which is provided via a REST API
What I don‘t understand is this:
Let‘s say I train the model with all the data till yesterday and this means I can predict the first values of today by a certain amount. But the new values of today have not been observed by the model that has been build yesterday.
How would you solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Djboblo,
I assume that you need to predict whole next day values on per minute basis.
In that case your options are:

1. recursive prediction, i.e. using predicted data as input for the next prediction
2. structuring the model to provide you with prediction for the whole next day

If it is just a matter of predicting for a single minute forward and your model is trained on reasonably large amount of data - don't worry, just feed it with the values up to the prediction minute. Periodically you may re-train the model using new data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I've looked into RNN with a sliding window to it
But say I want to predict the next 20min of data based on the size that I give to my window
Wouldn't there be any overlapping issued?

t-20_________t0__________t+20
At t0 I want to predict till t+20 and my model has finished training
But at t1 I have to train it again with the data from t19 to t0 wich takes some time
Or how would you solve this issue?

Comment: it is not necessary to re-train unless your data changed dramatically. just feed data from t-19  to t0 to your model for prediction.

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for is this:

[How to use a Keras RNN model to forecast for future dates or events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48760472/how-to-use-a-keras-rnn-model-to-forecast-for-future-dates-or-events)

to predict stateful events

and after a while use the .fit Method to update the network with new data

See: https://machinelearningmastery.com/update-lstm-networks-training-time-series-forecasting/