# What is the correct input shape of multivariate time series for LSTM in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I can not understand what is the right way to input multivariate time series to an LSTM.

Let's say i have a dataset with 3 features that vary over time like this:

| feat1 | feat2 | feat3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |

should I present this to my LSTM as it is using [numpy.vstack()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)? like this:

```
[[1,2,3],  
[4,5,6],  
[7,8,9]]
```

Or should i stack it by columns so that each row is the feature sequence using [numpy.column_stack()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)? like this:

```
[[1,4,7],  
[2,5,8],  
[3,6,9]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the keras LSTM [API](https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/lstm/):

> inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].

Therefore, the *features* (multiple variables) should be represented by the last dimension, which means your 1st suggestion is the right one.

Obs: The `batch` dimension should be only of concern if you aren't using the `fit` function for a whole dataset. Otherwise, if you are presenting a single example (for instance, in inference), you should also apply the [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) function in the 0th axis.