# Keras Lstm predicting next item, taking whole sequences or sliding window. Will sliding window need stateful LSTM?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, language-model, lstm-stateful

I have a sequence prediction problem in which, given the last `n` items in a sequence I need to predict next item.

I have more than 2 million  sequences  each with different `timesteps` (`length of sequence`), like some are just 5 and some are 50/60/100/200 upto 500.

```
    seq_inputs = [
    ["AA1", "BB3", "CC4",…,"DD5"], #length/timeteps 5
    ["FF1", "DD3", "FF6","KK8","AA5", "CC8",…, "AA2"]   #length/timeteps 50
   ["AA2", "CC8", "CC11","DD3", "FF6","AA1", "BB3",……,”DD11”]#length/timesteps 200
    ..
    ..
    ] # there are 2million + of them
```

For prediction next item in sequence, I `trim` sequences to 60 maximum length with `post/pre padding` and just take last element of all sequences

for e.g, X’s will be

```
[[0,0,0,….,'AA1', 'BB3', 'CC4'],#lenght 60
 [0,0,0,….,'FF1', 'DD3', 'FF6', 'KK8', 'AA5', 'CC8'],#lenght 60
 [0,0,0,….,'AA2', 'CC8', 'CC11', 'DD3', 'FF6', 'AA1', 'BB3']#lenght 60
 ....
 ]
```

and y is last element

```
['DD5', 'AA2', 'DD11',...]
```

First I tokenise them and convert them in numeric form using `keras tokenizer.text_to_sequence()`and reshape them to 60 time steps and one feature for every sequence:**

```
X = [
    [[0],[0],[0],[0],[1], ..., [10], [200], [5], [3], [90] ],
    [[0],[0],[0],[0],[95],...,  [15], [4],[11],[78], [43]]
    ..
    ..
    ] 
y = [40,3, ... , ... ]
```

I am using LSTMs with embedding like below

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocabulary_size, 32, input_length=seq_len)) #seq_length
model.add(LSTM(80,return_sequences=True))
..
..
model.fit(train_inputs,train_targets,epochs=50,verbose=1,batch_size=32)
```

For my problem of predicting next item in sequence, should  this approach (of trimming sequences to 60 max length with post/pre padding and just taking last item as target) good?
As target will be different timestep for each like 5th,50th,200th and so on , in my example.

Should I make every sequence n-gram/sliding window? For example for this first sequence of of my dataset

```
   ["AA1", "BB3", "CC4",…,"DD5"]
```

Sliding window of 5 , first example will be will be converted as

```
seq_inputs = [
   [0,0,0,0,"AA1"]
   [0,0,0,"AA1", "BB3"]
   [0,0,"AA1", "BB3","CC4"],
…,
... 
]
```

And similarly others will also be converted to sliding windows.

**To summarise the problem and questions again:**

With current approach, taking last element as `y`, I am struck at 30 validation accuracy, but my concern is not performance, my concern is if I am doing it right. So, Need guidance on following

1. Since I need to predict next item in sequence, is taking last item  as output for each sequence right approach?
2. Since my input length varies (from 5 to 500) and I am restricting it to 60 timesteps, should I increase or decrease it?
3. Instead of taking whole sequence should I take sliding window approach like I shared?
4. Will I need to have stateful LSTM in case of sliding windows?

Comment: Hi @A.B! Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @Arwen, in my case I tried both and the sliding window was over-fitting. So I end up using taking the last N tokens.