# How LSTM work with word embeddings for text classification, example in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to understand how LSTM is used to classify text sentences (word sequences) consists of pre-trained word embeddings. I am reading through some posts about lstm and I am confused about the detailed procedure:

IMDB classification using LSTM on keras:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/
Colah's explanation on LSTM:
http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/

Say for example, I want to use lstm to classify movie reviews, each review has fixed length of 500 words. And I am using pre-trained word embeddings (from fasttext) that gives 100-dimension vector for each word. What will be the dimensions of Xt to feed into the LSTM? And how is the LSTM trained? If each Xt is a 100-dimension vector represent one word in a review, do I feed each word in a review to a LSTM at a time? What will LSTM do in each epoch? I am really confused...

[image: lstm cell from Colah's blog]

```python
# LSTM for sequence classification in the IMDB dataset
import numpy
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset but only keep the top n words, zero the rest
top_words = 5000
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=top_words)
# truncate and pad input sequences
max_review_length = 500
X_train = sequence.pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_review_length)
X_test = sequence.pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_review_length)
# create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(top_words, embedding_vecor_length, input_length=max_review_length))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

In the above code example (taken from Jason Brownlee's blog https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), a LSTM of 100 cells/neurons is used. How is the 100 neurons interconnected? Why can't I just use 1 cell in the figure above for classification since it is a recurrent manner so it feeds the output back to itself in the next timestamp? Any visualization graphs will be welcome.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Shapes with the embedding:**

- Shape of the input data: `X_train.shape == (reviews, words)`, which is `(reviews, 500)`

**In the LSTM (after the embedding, or if you didn't have an embedding)**

- Shape of the input data: `(reviews, words, embedding_size)`:

  - `(reviews, 500, 100)` - where 100 was automatically created by the embedding
- Input shape for the model (if you didn't have an embedding layer) could be either:

  - `input_shape = (500, 100)`
  - `input_shape = (None, 100)` - This option supports variable length reviews
- Each `Xt` is a slice from `input_data[:,timestep,:]`, which results in shape:

  - `(reviews, 100)`
  - But this is entirely automatic, made by the layer itself.
- Each `Ht` is discarded, the result is only the last `h`, because you're not using `return_sequences=True` (but this is ok for your model).

Your code seems to be doing everything, so you don't have to do anything special to train this model. Use `fit` with a proper `X_train` and you will get `y_train` with shape `(reviews,1)`.

**Questions:**

> If each Xt is a 100-dimension vector represent one word in a review, do I feed each word in a review to a LSTM at a time?

No, the LSTM layer is already doing everything by itself, including all recurrent steps, provided its input has shape `(reviews, words, embedding_size)`

---

> How is the 100 neurons interconnected?

They are sort of parallel (you can imagine 100 images like the one you posted, all parallel), almost the same as other kinds of usual layers.

But during the recurrent steps, there is a matematical expression that make them conversate (unfortunately I can't explain exactly how).

---

> Why can't I just use 1 cell in the figure above for classification since it is a recurrent manner so it feeds the output back to itself in the next timestamp?

You can if you want, but the more cells, the smarter the layer (as happens with every other kind of layer)

There is nothing special about the number 100 chosen. It's probably a coincidence or a misunderstanding. It can be any number, 50 cells, 200 cells, 1000 cells...

---

**Understanding LSTMs deeply:**

- All types of usages, one to many, many to one, many to many: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50235563/2097240

Comment: "Each Xt is a slice from input_data[:,timestep,:], which results in shape:
(reviews, 100)" So for each timestamp, the input is based on the whole collection of reviews I got, but with only one of the 500 (or variable length) words in the sequence, correct? Can I assume the total number of timestamps to be 500 (if I use fixed 500 word length reviews)? Then the total number of iterations will be 500 timestamps * 3 epoches? Thanks for your really helpful answer! Do you have some recommendations of where I should read to have a deeper understanding of LSTM? Thanks!!

Comment: You're right. I think you've got a picture from one of the best texts I know. It's quite hard to find clear resources about LSTMs, and the link at the end of the answer is what I could understand with time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also, when does back propagation happens? Is it at the end of each epoch or each timestamp? For 500-word reviews, does it mean the longest dependency between words the LSTM can remember is 500, or it can be more than that? (like maybe extend to N*500, where N is the total number of reviews?)

Comment: 500 is the length you chose. All reviews are independent, their length won't sum up. Backpropagation happens once per batch.

Comment: Thanks! I see. I am wondering what "long term" memory refers in this LSTM in this case. My feeling is that it remembers the dependencies between one word and another that is remotely separated? But can it remember dependencies between words across different reviews? What type of long term dependencies does the LSTM capture in this case exactly? For simplification, assume each review has 500 words and are independent, does it capture the word dependencies within 500 timestamps range for each INDIVIDUAL review? I can't image how it is done by learning fixed size weights.

Answer (score 5):

You are confusing some terms, let's try to clarify what is going on step by step:

1. The data in your case will of shape (samples, 500) which means we have some number of reviews, each review is maximum 500 words encoded as integers.
2. Then the `Embedding` layer goes `words[index]` for every word in every sample giving a tensor (samples, 500, 100) if your embedding size is 100.
3. Now here is the confusing bit, when we say `LSTM(100)` it means a layer that runs a *single* LSTM cell (one like in Colah's diagram) over every word that has an output size of 100. Let me try that again, you create a single LSTM cell that transform the input into a 100 size output (hidden size) and the layer *runs* the same cell over the words.
4. Now we obtain (samples, 100) because the same LSTM processes every review of 500 words and return the final output which is of size 100. If for example we passed `return_sequences=True` then every hidden output, h-1, h, h+1 in the diagram would be returned so we would have obtained a shape (samples, 500, 100).
5. Finally, we pass the (samples, 100) to a `Dense` layer to make the prediction which gives (samples, 1) so a prediction for every review in the batch.

Take away lesson is that the `LSTM` *layer* wraps around a [LSTMCell](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#lstmcell) and runs it over every timestep for you so you don't have to write the loop operations yourself.