# Understanding multivariate time series classification with Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I am trying to understand how to correctly feed data into my keras model to classify multivariate time series data into three classes using a LSTM neural network.

I looked at different resources already - mainly these three excellent blog posts by Jason Brownlee [post1](https://machinelearningmastery.com/sequence-classification-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), [post2](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/), [post3](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/)), other SO [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms) and different [papers](https://github.com/titu1994/LSTM-FCN), but none of the information given there exactly fits my problem case, and I was not able to figure out if my data preprocessing / feeding it into the model is correct, so I guessed I might get some help if I specify my exact conditions here.

What I am trying to do is classify multivariate time series data, which in its original form is structured as follows:

- I have 200 samples
- One sample is one csv file.
- A sample can have 1 to 50 features (i.e. the csv file has 1 to 50 columns).
- Each feature has its value "tracked" over a fixed amount of time
  steps, let's say 100 (i.e. each csv file has exactly 100 rows).
- Each csv file has one of three classes ("good", "too small", "too big")

So what my current status looks like is the following:

I have a numpy array *"samples"* with the following structure:

```py
# array holding all samples
[
    # sample 1        
    [
        # feature 1 of sample 1 
        [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, ... ], # "time series" of feature 1
        # feature 2 of sample 1 
        [ 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, -0.1, -0.2, ... ], # "time series" of feature 2
        ... # up to 50 features
    ],
    # sample 2        
    [
        # feature 1 of sample 2 
        [ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.1, ... ], # "time series" of feature 1
        # feature 2 of sample 2 
        [ 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.6, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, -0.1, -0.2, ... ], # "time series" of feature 2
        ...  # up to 50 features
    ],
    ... # up to sample no. 200
]
```

I also have a numpy array *"labels"* with the same length as the *"samples"* array (i.e. 200). The labels are encoded in the following way:

- "good" = 0
- "too small" = 1
- "too big" = 2

```py
[0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, ... ] # up to label no. 200
```

This *"labels"* array is then encoded with keras' `to_categorical` function

```py
to_categorical(labels, len(np.unique(labels)))
```

My model definition currently looks like that:

```py
max_nb_features = 50
nb_time_steps = 100

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(5, input_shape=(max_nb_features, nb_time_steps)))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

- The 5 units in the LSTM layer are just randomly picked for now
- 3 Output neurons in the dense layer for my three classes

I then split the data into training / testing data:

```py
samples_train, samples_test, labels_train, labels_test = train_test_split(samples, labels, test_size=0.33)
```

This leaves us with 134 samples for training and 66 samples for testing.

The problem I'm currenty running into, is that the following code is not working:

```py
model.fit(samples_train, labels_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1)
```

The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm_test.py", line 152, in <module>
    model.fit(samples_train, labels_train, epochs=1, batch_size=1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 1002, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1630, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1476, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 113, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected lstm_1_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (134, 1)
```

For me, it seems to not work because of the variable amount of features my samples can have. 
If I use "fake" (generated) data, where all parameters are the same, except each sample has exactly the same amount of features (50), the code works.

**Now what I'm trying to understand is:**

1. Are my general assumptions on how I structured my data for the LSTM input correct? Are the parameters (`batch_size`, `input_shape`) correct / sensible?
2. Is the keras LSTM model in general able to handle samples with different amount of features?
3. If yes, how do I have to adapt my code for it to work with different amount of features?
4. If no, would "zero-padding" (filling) the columns in the samples with less than 50 features work? Are there other, preferred methods of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the input shape for Keras should be:

input_shape=(number_of_samples, nb_time_steps, max_nb_features).

And most often nb_time_steps = 1

P.S.: I tried solving a very similar problem for an internship position (but my results turned out to be wrong). You may take a look here: https://github.com/AbbasHub/Deep_Learning_LSTM/blob/master/2018-09-22_Multivariate_LSTM.ipynb (see if you can spot my mistake!)

Answer (score 1):

The LSTM model requires a 3D input in the form of [samples, time steps, features]

When defining the first layer of our LSTM model, we need to specify only the *time* *steps* and *features*. Even though this may seem 2D it is actually 3D as the *samples* size i.e. batch size is specified at the time of model fit.

```
features = x_train_d.shape[1]
```

Hence, we first need to reshape our input in the 3D format:

```
x_train_d = np.reshape(x_train_d, (x_train_d.shape[0], 1, x_train_d.shape[1]))
```

Here goes the LSTM first layer:

```
model.add(LSTM(5,input_shape=(1, features),activation='relu'))
```

And the model fit specifies the *samples*=50 as expected by LSTM

```
model.fit(x_train_d,y_train_d.values,batch_size=50,epochs=100)
```

For the question asked with variable length inputs, there is a discussion initiated at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/26366/training-an-rnn-with-examples-of-different-lengths-in-keras