# How to undestand timestamp in Keras LSTM

Tags: keras, timestamp, lstm

I am trying to understand interpretation of timestamp in **Keras LSTM**, for prediction longer period of time in forecasting.

I already read a lot of papers found in internet, and also here in stackoverflow ([Understanding Keras LSTMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms),but) I am still confused. I implemented Keras with timestamp = 1 and **predicting the weather  with shift for 1 hour**. The prediction is actually really good, what I have expected.

The problem occured in the moment when **I am trying to predict wheather shifted for 12 hours**. I am not sure how Keras is interpreting the backpropagation in this situation. How Keras is actually "remember" the previous data.

I have 7 columns with different type of data.  I am putting 8th one as predicted output. My reshape is prepared like below:

```py
#reshape((samples, timestamp, features))
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X= train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 1, train_X.shape[1]))
```

For prediction 12hours should it look like below ?

```py
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 12, train_X.shape[1]))
test_X= train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], 12, train_X.shape[1]))
```

I would like to get *more details about this part* of Keras LSTM implementation