# LSTM input longer than output

Tags: keras, lstm

I am not sure if I understand how exactly Keras version of LSTM works.
Let's say I have vector of len=20 as input and I specify keras.layers.LSTM(units=10)
So in this example does the network finish after processing 50% of input or it precess the rest from start (I mean from first cell)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Units are never related to the input size.
Units are related only to the output size (`units = output features or channels`).

An LSTM layer will always process the entire data and optionally return either the "same length (all steps)" or "no length (only last step)".

---

**In terms of shapes**

You must have an input tensor with shape `(batch, len=20, input_features)`.

And it will output:

- For `return_sequences=False`: `(batch, output_features=10)` - no length
- For `return_sequences=True`: `(batch, len=20, output_features=10)` - same length

Output features is always equal to `units`.

---

See a full comprehension of the LSTM layers here: [Understanding Keras LSTMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms/50235563#50235563)