# How to transform a simple series to feed into Keras LSTM?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I’ve get trouble for understand the LSTM input in keras. How I can transform a very simple serie 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 in a input matrix for it can predict next number?

I’m found that diagram

[image]

And I read some tutorials that they say matrix shape it’s like

```
[[0 1 2 3 4]
 [1 2 3 4 5]
 [2 3 4 5 6]
 [3 4 5 6 7]
 [4 5 6 7 8]]
```

I’ve made it with

```
list1 = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    list1.append(i)
list2 = []
list3 = []

for i in range(0, len(list1) - 5):
    list2.append(list1[i:i + 5])

list2 = np.array(list2)
```

But what does rows and columns represent respect that diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Keras LSTM layer has the following call argument [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM#call_arguments_2) :

> Call arguments:
>
> ```
> inputs: A 3D tensor with shape [batch, timesteps, feature].
> ```

The Matrix that you gave is of 2D shape `(5, 5)` i.e. 5 rows and 5 columns.

Since you are using LSTM, let me give you an example with text data:

> Cat sat on the dog

The above sentence has 5 words, each word can be vectorized into 5 dimensions (Word Embedding).
This makes your sentence become a tensor of 2D shape of `(5,5)`
Now you can have multiple sentences.

> - Dog sat on the cat
> - Cat ate the dog food
> - Dog ate the cat food

So now you have total 4 sentences which is your batch. Each of these 4 sentence will have a tensor of `(5,5)` since all have 5 words in them and you are encoding each word with 5 dimensions.

Thus your whole dataset has the shape:

```
[batch, timesteps, feature] == [4, 5, 5]
```

You can now feed this 3D tensor into your LSTM layer.

In case you just want to feed that 2D matrix you will have to expand the dimension using [np.expand_dims()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) to become `(1, 5, 5)` 3D shape

```
list2 = np.expand_dim(list2, axis=0)
print(list2)
print(list2.shape)
```

> ```
> [[[0 1 2 3 4]
>   [1 2 3 4 5]
>   [2 3 4 5 6]
>   [3 4 5 6 7]
>   [4 5 6 7 8]]]
> (1, 5, 5)
> ```

Also refer to [Understanding Keras LSTMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms)