# which type of input_shape should I use in tensorflow.keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am learning TensorFlow through its documentation and a little bit confused about the `input_shape` type in the first layer. Some of the examples have `list`, but usually, it is a tuple. Is there any specific case that I have to use a certain type?

```
# I am learning RNN and see this example.
tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, input_shape=[30])
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

vs

```
# This is what I usually see
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
tf.keras.layers.Dense(32)
```

It seems like it depends on my data and some other facts, but I don't know which one determines its type.

Comment: It does not really matter if you use a list or a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either a `list` or a `tuple` to define the input shape, they both give the same result, see this example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

>>> tf.keras.Input(shape=(10,))
<tf.Tensor 'input_1:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>

>>> tf.keras.Input(shape=[10])
<tf.Tensor 'input_2:0' shape=(?, 10) dtype=float32>

>>> tf.keras.Input(shape=(32,32,3))
<tf.Tensor 'input_3:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 3) dtype=float32>

>>> tf.keras.Input(shape=[32,32,3])
<tf.Tensor 'input_4:0' shape=(?, 32, 32, 3) dtype=float32>
```

It is up to you, there is no advantage or disadvantage of using the either. The same applies for `input_shape` in a layer.

Comment: Thanks for good explanation. I want to make sure I understand `The same applies for input_shape in a layer`. Do you mean it is okay to use tuple or list in any other first layers(ex, Dense, Conv2D, Lambda)?

Comment: @jayko03 Yes precisely.

Comment: gotcha. Thanks for help Dr.Snoopy!

Answer (score 0):

In `Keras`, the input layer itself is not a layer, it is a tensor. It's the starting tensor we send to the first hidden layer. A Keras `input_shape` argument requires a subscribable object in which the size of each dimension could be stored as an integer. Following are all the valid approaches:

```
tfd = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(3,))
x = tfd(tf.ones(shape=(5, 3)))
print(x.shape) # (5, 1)

or,

tfd = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[3])
x = tfd(tf.ones(shape=(5, 3)))
print(x.shape) # (5, 1)
```

Note, we can't pass only `input_shape=3` as it's not subscribable. Likewise,

```
tfd = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
x = tfd(tf.ones(shape=(5, 3)))
print(x.shape) # (5, 1)

or, 

tfd = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=[224, 224, 3])
x = tfd(tf.ones(shape=(5, 3)))
print(x.shape) # (5, 1)
```

This tensor must have the **same shape** as our **training data**. When you set `input_shape=(224, 224, 3)` that means you have training data which is an RGB image with the shape of `224 x 224`. The model never knows this shape at first, so we need to manually set it. This is mostly a general picture for Image modeling. And same as this goes to the RNN or sequence modeling: `input_shape=(None, features)` or `input_shape=(features, )`

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38714959/understanding-keras-lstms/50235563#50235563) answer for more sequence modeling approaches. Hope that helps.

Comment: This does not answer what the question is actually asking.

Comment: Please let the OP decide this. I felt this answered what he asked. If he confirms it's not what he wanted, I'll remove it.

Comment: No, we can also read, the question asks about type of the input shape (tuple or list), and your answer does not deal with that at all.

Comment: Yes, I informed it in the first paragraph of my answer. Or should I include more explanation?

Comment: Yes you could mention that a list and tuple both serve the same purpose and it does not matter which you use in this case

Comment: I'm not sure if the value of  `input_shape` can be set as `list` rather than `tuple`.  Please correct me. As I already asked OP, his `input_shape=[30]` statement confuses me a bit.

Comment: That detail is exactly what the question is about, which goes back to my first comment.

Comment: I know it is starting tensor which I have to pass specifically to the my layers. But I am confused with its type. As I asked in my question, I saw some example uses `input_shape=[ ]`, but I also saw `input_shape=( )`. So I was wondering which type of argument does `input_shape` take.

Comment: Thanks to @Dr.Snoopy. I updated my answer.